# PrimeNG Load DataTable after Filter is applied

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I'm getting the data from the API, and rendering it in **p-table**

Right after that I'm triggering the table filtering programmatically (default filter).

The problem I'm facing is that the Table is loaded and rendered without filter, and in few ms later filter is applied, and table re-rendered.

Is there a way to get the event which triggers the loading of Prime Table? Or delay it somehow.

Template:

```
<p-table #tt class="table"[value]="myList">
     ....
     <tr>
       <th>
        <p-dropdown appendTo="body" *ngSwitchCase="'state'" [options]="states"
        (onChange)="tt.filter($event.value, 'state', 'equals')"></p-dropdown>
       </th>
     </tr>
     ....
</p-table>
```

Class:

```
export class Component implements {
    @ViewChild('tt') tt: DataTable;
    myList: any;

    getList(){
    Promise.resolve(...)
        .then(res => {
                this.myList = res;
                this.tt.filter('created', 'state', 'equals');
              });
            }
     }
```

Comment: hi.. Have you got a solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

This filtering is like dependant on your markup, and markup will only appears only when you will get data from api call.

So best decision and the right way to perform this will be to sort your array inside of `then` callback programaticly like

`this.myList = res.sort(yourCustomSortFunction)`;

As i understood you need to render this immediatly, so why not to sort it in advance before template rendering at all.

Comment: I thought there was a more common solution. The logic of this is fine, how ever I needed to create custom sort function, instead of using the one from p-table. Thanks anyways